# Why does using MUI React components as child components produce errors during testing?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, material-ui, vitest

I have a parent component Navbar which have several MUI React child components. When I test the Navbar component with testing-library's render function it produces following error:

> Error: Uncaught [Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `Navbar`.

However, if I remove MUI React components from the Navbar, it doesn't produce the error anymore. How to fix this problem?

```
it('Should render all links', () => {
    const { getAllByRole } = render(
      <Router>
        <Navbar username="test username" logout={vi.fn()} />
      </Router>
    );
    const links = getAllByRole('link');
    expect(links[0]).toHaveTextContent(/ResourcePlanning/i);
    expect(links[1]).toHaveTextContent(/MobileView/i);
  });




export const Navbar = ({ username, logout }) => {
  const getTranslations = async () => {
    // todo
    window.location.reload();
  };

  return (
    <StyledNav>
      <StyleHeaderContainerDiv>
        <StyledHeaderSpan>Title</StyledHeaderSpan>
      </StyleHeaderContainerDiv>
      <StyledHeaderLinksContainer>
        <StyledLinkList>
          <StyledLink to="/">ResourcePlanning</StyledLink>
          <StyledLink to="/mobileview">MobileView</StyledLink>
        </StyledLinkList>
      </StyledHeaderLinksContainer>
      <StyleHeaderContainerDiv>
        <Icon path={mdiWeb} size={1.2} />
        <TranslationButton type="button" onClick={() => getTranslations()}>
          Get Translations
        </TranslationButton>
      </StyleHeaderContainerDiv>

      <StyleHeaderContainerDiv>
        <Button
          variant="outlined"
          style={{
            color: 'white',
            backgroundColor: '#555',
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: '10px',
            opacity: 0.9,
          }}
          onClick={() => logout()}
          startIcon={<Icon path={mdiLogout} size={1.2} style={{ opacity: 1 }} />}
        >
          {username}
        </Button>
      </StyleHeaderContainerDiv>
    </StyledNav>
  );
};
```

Removing  and  solves the problems as both are MUI components.

Comment: For better clarity, update some relevant code. Check you are wrapping your `NavBar` component with its providers (if any) also.

Comment: Thanks for advice, what do you mean with updating some relevant code?

Comment: with minimal version of your navbar code which can help to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with simple block of code importing MUI components. It seems working fine.

```
import { Container, Link } from "@mui/material";

export const Navbar = ({ username, logout }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>Title</span>
      </div>
      <Container>
        <Link to="/" data-testid={"link"}>
          ResourcePlanning
        </Link>
        <Link to="/mobileview" data-testid={"link"}>
          MobileView
        </Link>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};
```

NavBar.test.js

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Navbar } from "./NavBar";

it("Should render all links", () => {
  const { getAllByTestId } = render(
      <Navbar username="test username" logout={jest.fn()} />
  );
  const links = getAllByTestId("link");
  expect(links[0]).toHaveTextContent(/ResourcePlanning/i);
  expect(links[1]).toHaveTextContent(/MobileView/i);
});
```

Result:

```
PASS  src/components/NavBar.test.js
  ✓ Should render all links (64 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.089 s
```

Comment: your styled component might be the issue. Create a sandbox with your code and share so that others can help solve your issue.